# R factor analysis issue dealing with NA

Tags: r

I am just learning about factor analysis, and from what I have read there is no way, in R, to get a result for data that has NA's in every row (even though a row may have hundreds of complete datapoints). Is there any way to allow NA's? My dataset has at least one NA per row so removing all NA's isnt really an option for me. A simple example of my problem:

```
col1   col2   col3 ....
3      4       NA  ....
1      NA      NA  ....
NA     2       2   ....
```

My code:

```
#--------------------------------Factor Analysis--------------
#read in csv file with all data. stored in var called csv
nums<-sapply(csv,is.numeric)
num_only=csv[,nums]
num_only=na.omit(num_only)
matrix<-as.matrix(num_only)
anal<-factanal(matrix,rotation="promax")
```

My error (occurs because removing NA and non-numeric removes all data from matrix):

```
Error in factanal(matrix, rotation = "promax") : 
factor analysis applies only to numerical variables
```

Comment: can you pass a correlation matrix using `pairwise` correlations?

Comment: take a look at the `missMDA` package.  `factanal` like most Factor Analyses functions can't handle missing data

Comment: Imputation is not an option? See `mi` package.